# TFormatSettings.Create returns incorrect formats

Tags: delphi, formatdatetime

When doing a TFormatSettings.Create I get the following formats

```
ShortDateFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy'
ShortTimeFormat: 'hh:mm'
```

However according to the various FormatDateTime docs, the month should be "mm" and the minutes should be "nn"

Is it a bug/locale issue, or do these really use another incompatible format convention?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FormatDateTime) for `mm` says, with my emphasis:

> Displays the month as a number with a leading zero (01-12). **If the mm specifier immediately follows an h or hh specifier, the minute rather than the month is displayed.**

Comment: Thanks, had overlooked it!

Comment: Poor. So we cannot express that something happened at 12 in the 3rd month.

Comment: @LURD, how, if `h m` gives you `hour minute` instead of `hour month` (and no concatenation *cheats*, please :) ?

Comment: @TLama,  `FormatSettings.ShortTimeFormat := 'hh'; WriteLn(FormatDateTime('t m',Now));`

Comment: @LURD, ok, you got me (I should have set stricter rules :) Still, I think this *feature* should not exist.

Comment: @TLama looks like a hack to support the subset of C-style date-time format strings you can encounter in default Windows locale formats

Comment: And let's not forget, these formatting strings are coming from OS configurations, not the RTL.  So it is the OS that is using `mm` for minutes, for instance.  The RTL simply supports that usage as needed.